# Unittesting when using Android Annotations, Mockito and MVP pattern

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing, android-mvp

I've up until yesterday successfully put together a very readable Android project using the MVP-pattern and the [Android Annotations library](http://androidannotations.org/).

But yesterday when I started writing unittest for my LoginPresenter a problem has shown itself.

First some code from my LoginPresenter.

```
...
@EBean
public class LoginPresenterImpl implements LoginPresenter, LoginInteractor.OnLoginFinishedListener {

  @RootContext
  protected LoginActivity loginView;

  @Bean(LoginInteractorImpl.class)
  LoginInteractor loginInteractor;

  @Override public void validateCredentials(String username, String password) {
    if (loginView != null) {
        loginView.showProgress();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        // Check that username isn't empty
        onUsernameError();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        // Check that password isn't empty
        onPasswordError();
        // No reason to continue to do login
    } else {

    }
}

  @UiThread(propagation = UiThread.Propagation.REUSE)
  @Override public void onUsernameError() {
    if (loginView != null) {
        loginView.setUsernameError();
        loginView.hideProgress();
    }
}

...
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginPresenterImplTest {

  private LoginPresenter loginPresenter;

  @Mock
  private LoginPresenter.View loginView;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
      // mock or create a Context object
      Context context = new MockContext();

      loginPresenter = LoginPresenterImpl_.getInstance_(context);

      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
      loginPresenter = null;

  }

  @Test
  public void whenUserNameIsEmptyShowUsernameError() throws Exception {
      loginPresenter.validateCredentials("", "testtest");

      // verify(loginPresenter).onUsernameError();
      verify(loginView).setUsernameError();
  }
}
```

The problem is I've not used the standard approach of using MVP-pattern but instead trying out Android Annotations to make the code more readable. So I've not used attachView()- or detachView()-methods for attaching my presenter to my LoginActivity (view). This means that I can't mock my "view". Does someone know a workaround for this problem. I keep getting following message when running the test:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
loginView.setUsernameError();
-> at      com.conhea.smartgfr.login.LoginPresenterImplTest.whenUserNameIsEmptyShowUsernameError(LoginPresenterImplTest.java:48)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

**Solution (I'm not using @RootContext anymore):**

Presenter:

```
@EBean
public class LoginPresenterImpl extends AbstractPresenter<LoginPresenter.View>
        implements LoginPresenter, LoginInteractor.OnLoginFinishedListener {

    private static final String TAG = LoginPresenterImpl.class.getSimpleName();

    @StringRes(R.string.activity_login_authenticating)
    String mAuthenticatingString;

    @StringRes(R.string.activity_login_aborting)
    String mAbortingString;

    @StringRes(R.string.activity_login_invalid_login)
    String mInvalidCredentialsString;

    @StringRes(R.string.activity_login_aborted)
    String mAbortedString;

    @Inject
    LoginInteractor mLoginInteractor;

    @Override
    protected void initializeDagger() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Dagger injection");
        Log.d(TAG, "Application is :" + getApp().getClass().getSimpleName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Component is: " + getApp().getComponent().getClass().getSimpleName());
        Log.d(TAG, "UserRepo is: " + getApp().getComponent().userRepository().toString());
        mLoginInteractor = getApp().getComponent().loginInteractor();
        Log.d(TAG, "LoginInteractor is: " + mLoginInteractor.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void validateCredentials(String username, String password) {
        boolean error = false;
        if (!isConnected()) {
            noNetworkFailure();
            error = true;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username.trim())) {
            // Check that username isn't empty
            onUsernameError();
            error = true;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password.trim())) {
            // Check that password isn't empty
            onPasswordError();
            error = true;
        }
        if (!error) {
            getView().showProgress(mAuthenticatingString);
            mLoginInteractor.login(username, password, this);
        }
    }
...
```

My tests (some of them):

```
@RunWith(AppRobolectricRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class LoginPresenterImplTest {

@Rule
public MockitoRule mMockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

private LoginPresenterImpl_ mLoginPresenter;

@Mock
private LoginPresenter.View mLoginViewMock;

@Mock
private LoginInteractor mLoginInteractorMock;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<LoginInteractor.OnLoginFinishedListener> mCaptor;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    mLoginPresenter = LoginPresenterImpl_.getInstance_(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
    mLoginPresenter.attachView(mLoginViewMock);
    mLoginPresenter.mLoginInteractor = mLoginInteractorMock;
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mLoginPresenter.detachView();
    mLoginPresenter = null;

}

@Test
public void whenUsernameAndPasswordIsValid_shouldLogin() throws Exception {

    String authToken = "Success";

    mLoginPresenter.validateCredentials("test", "testtest");

    verify(mLoginInteractorMock, times(1)).login(
            anyString(),
            anyString(),
            mCaptor.capture());
    mCaptor.getValue().onSuccess(authToken);
    verify(mLoginViewMock, times(1)).loginSuccess(authToken);
    verify(mLoginViewMock, times(1)).hideProgress();
}

@Test
public void whenUsernameIsEmpty_shouldShowUsernameError() throws Exception {

    mLoginPresenter.validateCredentials("", "testtest");


    verify(mLoginViewMock, times(1)).setUsernameError();
    verify(mLoginViewMock, never()).setPasswordError();
    verify(mLoginViewMock, never()).hideProgress();
}
...
```

Comment: Then what was the right way to test Presenter with @RootContext? Can you publish your final working result?

Comment: @aleksandrbel Check my edited questiion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can have this:

```
public class LoginPresenterImpl ... {

    ...

    @VisibleForTesting
    public void setLoginPresenter(LoginPresenter.View loginView) {
        this.loginView = loginView;
    }

}
```

In test class:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    ...

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    loginPresenter.setLoginPresenter(loginView);
}
```

**But**, as a rule of thumb, when you see `@VisibleForTesting` annotation, that means you have ill architecture. Better to refactor your project.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. The only thing that worked was a refactoring where I added attachView and detachView metheds.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up to Developers that want to use Android Annotations in their project. Watch out when writing unittests that your code doesn't access the Android APIs. The underlying implementation of Android Annotations is heavily dependent on the Android APIs. So the code that is autogenerated could be dependent on this and make it difficult to write unittests.

Always remember that Android Annotations replaces your class with a final class that has an _ added at the end of it's classname. In this generated class a lot of boilerplate code is autogenerated depending on how the original class is annotated. In my case the problem is that I'm working on an Android-project and want a lot of my methods from my presenter to run on the UI-thread. This is achieved using Android Annotations using the @UIThread annotation. But this means that my method is actually wrapped with another method that calls the super-class:

```
@Override
public void onUsernameError() {
    if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
        LoginPresenterImpl_.super.onUsernameError();
        return;
    }
    UiThreadExecutor.runTask("", new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            LoginPresenterImpl_.super.onUsernameError();
        }
    }
    , 0L);
}
```

My testcase can't get past the line:

```
...
if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
...
```

And that is of course because we don't have access to the Android APIs in a simple unittest. So in there lies the problem.

Conclusion: You have to be very careful when writing unittests for projects using Android Annotations, that the code that is autogenerated doesn't rely on Android related APIs.

It's the same problem when using androids TextUtil-class.

Comment: Using Robolectric as your testrunner would make this run without problems.